# How To Make New Columns Based On Multiple Regular Expressions

Tags: python, sql, regex

I am trying to select two columns ('column1', 'column2'), filter out by dates in 'column1', and select only the values as per the below regular expressions from column2 in database using a SQL query in Python:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM data
WHERE column1 >= '2010-01-01' AND column1 <= '2010-12-01'
AND (
     column2 REGEXP 'HAPPY' OR
     column2 REGEXP 'JOYFUL' OR
     column2 REGEXP 'BAD'
)
"""
```

The above code works fine. However, I want to make a new column (say, new_column1) if the regular expression is 'HAPPY' or 'JOYFUL' and make another new column (say, new_column2) if the regular expression is 'BAD'.

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your logic considerably:

```
SELECT column1, column2,
       (CASE WHEN column2 REGEXP 'HAPPY|JOYFUL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as happy_flag,
       (CASE WHEN column2 REGEXP 'BAD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as bad_flag
FROM data
WHERE column1 >= '2010-01-01' AND column1 <= '2010-12-01' AND
      column2 REGEXP 'HAPPY|JOYFUL|BAD' ;
```

Note:  If you just want to compare the entire value, then use `IN`:

```
      column2 LIKE ('HAPPY', 'JOYFUL', 'BAD')
```

This is much more efficient than regular expression processing.